# c++ multithreaded task queue for scheduled tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I need to develop a module which will execute scheduled tasks.
Each task is scheduled to be executed within X milliseconds.

The module takes as a parameter an amount of worker threads to execute the tasks.

The tasks are piled up in a queue which will probably be a priority queue, so a thread checks for the next-in-queue task (the one with the lowest "redemption" time), thus there's no need to iterate through all tasks each time.

Is there any public library that does that or shall I roll my own?

Note: I'm using VC2008 on Windows.

Comment: Couple of years back, I was implemented a thread pool library (very simplistic); and open sourced it.
http://shobhitgupta12.blogspot.com/2008/03/thread-pool-implementation-using-c.html
It was a personal project, so I didn't do very good documentation. Not an exact solution to your problem, but atleast you have something to look at now... You anyway will have to implement a thread pool mechanism, and this can help.

Comment: In VC 2010 the Parallel Pattern Library, Asynchronous Agents Library and Concurrency Runtime were added explicitly to make these scenarios more productive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind a Boost dependency, [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) might fit your needs.

Comment: It looks like threadpoool will eventually implement a deadline scheduler, but for now, the closest it has is a priority scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at TBB - [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little information to your question, what you're asking for is a real-time scheduler that uses the [Earliest Deadline First](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling) algorithm.  Also note that without OS support, you can't guarantee that your program will work in that X millisecond deadline you assign it.  The OS could always decide to swap your task off its CPU in the middle of the job, making it take an unpredictably-long time to complete.

If your application critically depeneds on the task being done in the X milliseconds you set for it (or something blows up), you'll need to be running a [real-time operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), not regular Windows.

Comment: First of all thank you! Now, I think I'm a bit misunderstood - my need is for a good task-queue implementation that does it like the Earliest Deadline First algorithm you posted, in a manner that it checks only the first task in the queue, and in a manner that whena task is submitted to the engine, it's being inserted to the queue having a priority relative to other existing tasks, so for example if I post 3 tasks, the first is to be executed within 3sec, 2nd within 2sec and 3rd within 6sec, then the 2nd will be the first to be executed.

Comment: (continue) If after 1sec I pass another task (4rd) that should be executed within 4sec, it'll be executed before the 3rd task and after the 1st task (was set to be fired within 3sec).

Comment: So, it doesn't matter to me if a task will take a bit too long and make other tasks executed some time after their original redemption time (I'll handle it).